# Haskell intersect two lists and remove double elements

Tags: list, haskell

I'm new to Haskell and need an function to intersect two lists, but remove double elements.

If I load the Data.List

```
import Data.List
```

I can use this function:

```
intersect "abbcd" "abbe"
"abb"
```

The outcome is "abb", but what I need is:

```
   intersectFunction "abbcd" "abbe"
    "ab"
```

So the double char from the lists should display only once.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps the "unique" function named *nub* can help:

```
import Data.List

intersectFunction a b = nub $ intersect a b
```

Comment: Thanks you. Maybe you can help me to get this in a program that I can load? So that I basically only need to give intersectFunction abbcd abbe and I get ab as return. So the code has to be programed in notepad for example.

Comment: @user2021386 You can use notepad, but I would recommend at least using Notepad++.  Notepad is not designed for entering code and there's a lot of incredibly useful features you'd be living without.  Personally, I use Sublime Text, but there are many out there that can handle Haskell code quite well.  What vikingsteve has provided is not actually a function either, it's just an expression.  You'd have to bind that expression to a name, something like `myIntersect xs ys = nub $ intersect xs ys` for it to be a function.  You also need to make sure to have the Haskell Platform installed.

Comment: updated my answer as requested, it's now a program, save it as `whatever.hs`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `intersect` function you have, but then you need to remove the duplicate elements. It seems likely that there's a library function to do this, but how can we find it if we don't know the name?

The best way to answer questions of the form "Is there a Haskell function to do X" is usually:

1. Figure out what the type signature of the function you want would be.

In this case, we want a function that takes a list and produces a list. So the type signature is [a] -> [a]

1. Search [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=) or [hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html?query=). If you don't find it in one, try the other. Usually it doesn't matter much whether you get the order of the input parameters exactly right, but you may need to experiment.

In this case, there are quite a few functions with that type signature. But if you go to the second page of results, you'll find the `nub` function, which does what you need.

Comment: Thanks. First of all, I understand how to use the nub function with intersect, basically what vikingsteve said. But what I want is load the program, so that I basically only need to give intersectFunction abbcd abbe and I get ab as return. So the code has to be programed in notepad for example.